# Angular - Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using angular 5 and I'm getting the console error:

> Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of
>   'mat-option'

My template looks something like as follows:

```
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Book" name="patient" [(ngModel)]="selectedBook">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let eachBook of books" [ngValue]="eachBook">{{eachBook.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

I've imported both `MatSelectModule` and `MatOptionModule`.

How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use value

```
[value]="eachBook"
```

Comment: I want to use `ngValue` instead of `value` which is what angular docs recommends. How can I use `ngValue` ?

Comment: as Mark answered value and [ngValue] serve different purposes

Comment: if the value is not string then [ngValue] needed to use. Is there any way around to use the material select box and with [ngValue]?

Comment: For Mat-Option and I believe other Angular material components, [value] does work with objects and ngValue is not needed.

Comment: You should not use [value], since there are times when you need [ngValue], how is this accepted?

Answer (score 23):

The accepted answer is not a solution but a work-around, as `value` and `[ngValue]` serve different purposes. `value` can be used for simple string values, whereas `[ngValue]` is necessary to support non-string values.

Per the documentation:

> If you have imported the FormsModule or the ReactiveFormsModule, this
>   value accessor will be active on any select control that has a form
>   directive. You do not need to add a special selector to activate it.

If you are getting this error, you most likely need to import either `FormsModule` or `ReactiveFormsModule` into your app.

For example, in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// ...

imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ...
]
```

Comment: For Mat-Option and I believe other Angular material components, [value] does work with objects and ngValue is not needed.

Comment: @Alex Gah why couldn't they have just kept the name the same or aliased them or something...

Answer (score 2):

I have met the same issue. The solution for me is to import 'ReactiveFormsModule'.
So you can use `[ngValue]` to bind an object.

Comment: Imported ReactiveFormsModule but, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

for mat-autocomplete, to use items instead of strings, for mat-option, ngValue wasn't available, however with [value], we can access the object by using option.value instead of option.viewValue:

```
allFruits: Item[] = [
    {
      name: 'hello',
      selected: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'world',
      selected: false,
    }
  ];


<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit.name}} {{fruit.selected}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>


selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    console.log('selected ', event.option.value); <----- THIS
    console.log('selected ', event.option.viewValue); <---- NOT THIS
}
```

with option.value you get the object. With option.viewValue you will get a string representation of the innerHTML that the user sees.