# How to use full objects in Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am updating some old angular forms and have an issue with setting the form to an entire instance of an object while also being able to set the initial value.

I have tried setting the `[value]="option"` to the entire object while having `{{ option.$type }}` but the initial value doesn't show up. I have also tried using `[ngValue]` but I get an error even when I import `ReactiveFormModule`

Current code:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="49">
    <mat-select placeholder="Type" formControlName="type" autocomplete="off" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of container$ | async" [value]="option.$type">{{ option.$type }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I would prefer to have the whole container object as the value so I am able to access the `option.$id` later, but

```
this.editContainerForm.controls['type'].setValue(this.containerContext.$containerTypeName );
```

stops working even if i set the form with the entire container object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object are compared by reference in that case in order to use object as value must be the same reference

this mean

```
const a = {type$ : 'A'};
const a2 = {type$:'A'}; 

console.log(a === a2); // false
```

if you try to use object both object has to be the same refrence

```
  const a = {type$ : 'A'};
  const a2 = a; 

  console.log(a === a2); // true
```

basic example

```
  form:FormGroup;
  container$;

  data = [
      {$type:'A'},
      {$type:'B'},
      {$type:'C'},
    ]
  constructor(fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      type:this.data[1]
    })

    this.container$ = of(this.data)
  }
```

as you can see type has a value of the same refrence check the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdmswo)

**Updated! ✨**

you can provide `[compareWith][2]` a function to compare the option values with the selected values. The first argument is a value from an option. The second is a value from the selection. A boolean should be returned.

```
  compareWith(value , selectedValue ) {
    return value.$type === selectedValue.$type
  }
```

template

```
<mat-select placeholder="Type" formControlName="type" autocomplete="off" required [compareWith]="compareWith">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of container$ | async" [value]="option" >{{ option.$type }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdmswo-jpzdkm)

Comment: Do you know of anyway to use the [ngValue] instead? It would seem to me that is what i am supposed to do, but it doesn't work on mat-option

Comment: @NathanElg ngValue will not work for mat-option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782240/angular-cant-bind-to-ngvalue-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-mat-option

Comment: Dang, i don't think I can use the same reference since i am using the async pipe with a list, or I just don't understand enough to do it.

Comment: I have found a way by provide the compareWith method check the updated answer @NathanElg

Comment: i found how to set the value but i still have no way of grabbing the entire object when the user submits.

Comment: This doesn't actually end up solving the issue. I still can't access the id in this senario

Comment: @NathanElg you need to update the initail value after you got the complate data from api as example check this    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdmswo-mtjmul