# Using ngValue with Angular Material autocomplete?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am passing in an object as my value and need to use [ngValue] as opposed to [value].

My HTML looks like this:

```
<mat-input-container fxFlex="18" fxFlexOffset="1">
    <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Example"
        [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete"
        [ngModel]="user?.UserName"
        (ngModelChange)="filter($event)"
        [disabled]="disabled"/>
     <mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" 
                       (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event)" >
         <mat-option *ngFor="let selectedUser of availableUsers" [ngValue]="selectedUser">
             <span>{{ selectedUser?.UserName }}</span>
         </mat-option>
     </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-input-container>
```

As a demo, I also have a stackblitz with my error provided here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wk4rl?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html

I am getting the error:

Template parse errors:

```
Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'.

1. If 'mat-option' is an Angular component and it has 'ngValue' input, then verify that 
   it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
   '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the 
   '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

As mentioned in other answer on stack, [Angular - Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782240/angular-cant-bind-to-ngvalue-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-mat-option)

Users are suggesting that adding it to the modules file will solve the issue but when I tried that (as seen in my material-module.ts in my stackblitz), the error persists.

Any suggestions? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You can't use ngValue property binding with mat-option because it's only supposed to be used with `option` element. `mat-option` takes `[value]` bindings

Comment: Why do you want to have objects as autocomplete option values (instead of strings)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan because sometimes data models use objects not strings.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I've updated the html in my example to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
```

Check the documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

To use the object:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option 
    *ngFor="let selectedUser of availableUsers" [value]="selectedUser">
      {{selectedUser.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

in xxx.ts file:

```
displayFn(user?): string | undefined {
  return user ? user.name : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Yes - this works. I am wondering if there is the way I can get [ngValue] to work instead of [value].

Comment: No. Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: why do you need to use [ngValue]?

Comment: if I use [value]="selectedUser", then while the dropdown is populated correctly, my selection appears as '[object Object]' instead of the user's username.

While I could theoretically, use [value]="selectedUser?.UserName" - when I am saving, I'd like to save the entire object itself - and pass the object, not just the UserName because there are other dropdowns with different attribute to 'User' that could be changed

Comment: I see. You can try this, just display the name in it, you still pass the object to [value]: <mat-option *ngFor="let option of group.options" [value]="option"> {{option.name}} </mat-option>

Comment: Use `<mat-autocomplete [displayWith]="displayFn" ...>`. See https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values.

Comment: @katwhocodes yes - sorry I forgot to mention, I've updated the html in my post to clarify of what I have right now

Comment: @Jedo I see, you can use the displayWith then. I updated the answer

Comment: @katwhocodes thank you for the suggestion! works :)